# How can i set timeout for individual rest calls in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, openfeign

I am using spring boot starter web for rest api methods. I need to set custom timeout for individual rest calls. How is it possible ?
Similarly I am using feign clients, I would like to set timeout for individual feign methods also.

Comment: Have you tried to check this out? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-timeout
It have various ways

Comment: @GvSharma yeah I checked it looks like only resilience4j can address the problem I raised. Looking for a better solution